# Using Stirling numbers to find integers $a_k$ such that $4x^4-2x^2+5x-1=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k(x)_k$?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

> Find integers $a_k$ such that $4x^4-2x^2+5x-1=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k(x)_k$

I'm guessing the Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind will be used: $\sum_{k\ge 0}S(n,k)x^k=(x)_n$

The first thing I did was I set up $$4\bigg(S(4,0)(x)_0+S(4,1)(x)_1+S(4,2)(x)_2+S(4,3)(x)_3+S(4,4)(x)_4\bigg)-2\bigg(S(2,0)(x)_0+S(2,1)(x)_1+S(2,2)(x)_2\bigg)+5\bigg(S(1,0)(x)_0+S(1,1)(x)_1\bigg)$$

Which equals $$-1(x)_0+7(x)_1+26(x)_2+24(x)_3+4(x)_4=\sum_{k=0}^{4?}?(x)_k$$

My question is simply **how do I find $a_k$ and does expanding $4x^4-2x^2+5x-1$ help?**

Comment: I'm super confused. Do you want to find $a_k$ so that your polynomial is $$\sum_k a_k x^{\underline{k}}?$$ That is, do you want to rewrite it as a sum of [falling powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)? If not, why can't we take $a_0 = -1$, $a_1 = 5$, $a_2 = -2$, $a_3 = 0$, $a_4 = 4$, and $a_k = 0$ for $4k \geq 5$? Also, if you _are_ interested in falling powers, you might want to check out an [old blog post](https://grossack.site/2021/05/13/stirling-basis-change.html) of mine where (among other things) I talk about doing this conversion.

Comment: If the question as written is what you're looking for, then you don't need stirling numbers at all. You can just take $a_k$ to be the coefficients of $x^k$. What makes you think stirling numbers would be relevant?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor because this homework came after learning about the Stirling numbers. The question is exactly as asked, so maybe it's a miscommunication by the instructor.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor wait no, my bad! I'm so sorry, it should be a falling factorial. I'll change that now

Answer (score 1):

Since Stirling numbers are sought to determine $a_k$ it seems we should use ${{n}\brace {k}}$ the *[Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* which fulfill the relation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{{n}\brace{k}} (x)_k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> &4x^4-2x^2+5x-1=\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k(x)_k\\
> &\qquad=4\sum_{k=0}^{4}{{4}\brace{k}}(x)_k-2\sum_{k=0}^2{{2}\brace{k}}(x)_k
> +5\sum_{k=0}^1{{1}\brace{k}}(x)_k-1\\
> &\qquad=4{{4}\brace{4}}(x)_4+4{{4}\brace{3}}(x)_3+\left(4{{4}\brace{2}}-2{{2}\brace{2}}\right)(x)_{2}\\
> &\qquad\quad+\left(4{{4}\brace{1}}-2{{2}\brace{1}}+5{{1}\brace{1}}\right)(x)_{1}\\
> &\qquad\quad+\left(4{{4}\brace{0}}-2{{2}\brace{0}}+5{{1}\brace{0}}-1\right)(x)_{0}\\
> \end{align*}
> with $a_k$ explicitly stated in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of Stirling numbers-those expressing a power as a sum of falling factorials and those expressing a falling factorial as a sum of powers. You could (i) find a table of Stirling numbers of the appropriate kind or (ii) generate such a table by the approprite recursive relation or (iii) find each needed power on an ad hoc basis. I;ll lead you through (iii), using the notation $$ x^{(0)}=1,x^{(1)}=x,x^{(n)}=x(x-1)...(x-n+1)$$ Thus $$x^2=x(x-1)+x=x^{(2)}+x^{(1)}$$ $$x^3=x^2x=x^{(2)}x+x^{(1)}x=x^{(2)}(x-2+2)+x^{(2)}+x^{(1)}$$ $$=x^{(3)}+2x^{(2)}+x^{(2)}+x^{(1)}=x^{(3)}+3x^{(2)}+x^{(1)}$$ $$x^4=x^{(4)}+3x^{(3)}+3(x^{(3)}+2x^{(2)})+x^{(2}+x^{(1)}$$ which I'll let you simplify.Then we'll use the forward difference notation $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ and the 'telescoping series' formula$$\sum_{x-a}^b\Delta f(x)=f(b+1)-f(a).$$ Then use the fact that $$x^{(n)}=\frac{\Delta x^{(n+1)}}{n+1}$$ to do the summation.

Comment: What’s wrong with the way I did it? How would (i) work?

Comment: I guess I don’t follow what’s happening here